# JavaScript: how do I remove all the white spaces from a JSON string except the ones in the values?

Tags: javascript, regex, json

Given the following json...

```
var body = "{ \"name\": \"test\", \"description\": \"test json\", \"website\": \"domain.com\" }"
```

... how do I remove all the white spaces except the ones in the values?

I've tried the following regexp...

```
var body = "{ \"name\": \"test\", \"description\": \"test json\", \"website\": \"domain.com\" }".replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "").replace(/\s+/g, "")
```

... but it also removes the spaces in the values (i.e. `description`):

```
{"name":"test","description":"testjson","website":"domain.com"}
```

I need to obtain

```
{"name":"test","description":"test json","website":"domain.com"}
```

Tx.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of JSON, because that's not JSON, that's a JavaScript object. You want `JSON.stringify(body)`

Comment: `JSON.stringify(body)` returns it without spaces. Did you try to see if there are spaces before trying to remove it from there?

Comment: @zerkms Hmm, is that standard/guaranteed behavior?

Comment: In the real example I get a JSON string with white spaces... Let me fix the example in my post.

Comment: For the new version of question: `parse` first, then `stringify`

Comment: Please do not fundamentally change questions more than a minute after asking them. It's not nice to make us write correct answers to the wrong questions and make us do double work that way.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
var body = ' { "name": "test", "description": "test json", "website": "domain.com" } ';
JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body))
```

Returns:

```
{"name":"test","description":"test json","website":"domain.com"}
```

Which is exactly what you want. And yes, `JSON.stringify` with 1 parameter is guaranteed to give the shortest possible JSON, meaning no obsolete whitespace outside keys and values. That's the default because JSON is, in nearly all situations, intended to be a highly efficient recursive data serialization method - unnecessary whitespace has no use there by default.

[The full syntax is actually](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
JSON.stringify(value[, replacer [, space]])
```

The optional third parameter defaults to `false` - if set to another value it produces 'pretty print' with extra whitespace or lead-in strings:

> The space argument may be used to control spacing in the final string.
>   If it is a number, successive levels in the stringification will each
>   be indented by this many space characters (up to 10). If it is a
>   string, successive levels will indented by this string (or the first
>   ten characters of it).

As a final note, you shouldn't even *want* to use a regexp for this. Regexps are for making sense out of character patterns, not for processing structured data like XML, HTML or JSON. In those cases, use an XML, DOM or JSON parser respectively and process the results in there.

Comment: I've just updated my post... I get a json string containing white spaces... so invoking stringify doesn't work for me.

Comment: Updated the answer. Obviously, use `JSON.parse` first to make it a valid object, then re-`stringify` it.

Answer (score 4):

Parse the JSON, then stringify it again. Parsing it will convert the JSON to a Javascript object, and then stringifying it will return the shortest JSON representation:

```
var body = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse("{ \"name\": \"test\", \"description\": \"test json\", \"website\": \"domain.com\" }"));
```